# Problem with ActionChains - Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, bots, browser-automation

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://cpstest.org/")
myLinkManual= WebDriverWait(driver,1).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myLinkManual")))
clicker = WebDriverWait(driver,1).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "start")))
bttnstp= WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "btnstop")))

actions = ActionChains(driver)

actions.click(myLinkManual)
for i in range(20)
    actions.click(clicker)

actions.perform()
```

I just want to navigate to the other page by clicking the locator i.e. myLinkManual
after that, on that page, I want to click on a particular area 20 times but, when I'm executing this code it's not working but when I execute only one action i.e. click(myLinkManual) or click(clicker), it works fine. Do tell me if I'm doing something wrong 'cause I'm new to this.
Thank You

Comment: actions.perform() is the key.

Comment: Can you be more specific that how can I overcome this problem?